# Нужна помощь по простой css анимации

Tags: html, css, css-animation, keyframes

Даю скрин с заданием и с тем на что ума хватило
Понимаю, что нужно прописать через ховер + оверфлоу (возможно), но не понимаю как это сделать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.out-4-inner {
  text-align: center;
}

.out-4-inner:hover>.out-4 {
  animation-name: kqkq;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes kqkq {
  0% {}
  50% {}
  100% {}
}

.bg-orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="out-4 bg-orange">
  <div class="out-4-inner"> <span>Left</span> <span>Center</span> <span>Right</span> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: По скринам очень плохо понимать. Приложите код в виде текста.

Comment: <div class="out-4 bg-orange">
                <div class="out-4-inner">
                    <span>Left</span>
                    <span>Center</span>
                    <span>Right</span>
                </div>
            </div>

css
.out-4-inner {
    text-align: center;
}

.out-4-inner:hover > .out-4 {
    animation-name: kqkq;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes kqkq {
    0% {

    }
    50% {

    }
    100% {

    }
}

Comment: Обновите ваш вопрос воспользовавшись кнопкой "править"(ниже самого вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
:root {
  --duration: 2s;
  --fill-mode: forwards;
  --timing-function: linear;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-orange {
  background: orange;
}

.out-4 {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}

.out-4-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: kqkq var(--duration) var(--timing-function) var(--fill-mode);
}

.out-4-inner span:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 0;
  animation: right var(--duration) var(--timing-function) var(--fill-mode);
}

.out-4-inner span:nth-child(2) {
  animation: center var(--duration) var(--timing-function) var(--fill-mode);
}

.out-4-inner span:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 0;
  animation: left var(--duration) var(--timing-function) var(--fill-mode);
}

.out-4-inner,
.out-4-inner span:nth-child(1),
.out-4-inner span:nth-child(2),
.out-4-inner span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.out-4:hover .out-4-inner,
.out-4:hover .out-4-inner span:nth-child(1),
.out-4:hover .out-4-inner span:nth-child(2),
.out-4:hover .out-4-inner span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes kqkq {
  0% {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  0%,
  49% {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  50%,
  99% {
    font-size: inherit;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes center {
  0%,
  49% {
    font-size: inherit;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    font-size: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes left {
  0%,
  99% {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="out-4 bg-orange">
  <div class="out-4-inner">
    <span>Left</span>
    <span>Center</span>
    <span>Right</span>
  </div>
</div>
```